# What is the difference between good_sites and trusted_sites?

Tags: squid

The `squid.conf` file contains two lists of allowable domains, but I don't fully understand the difference between the two lists, one is called `good_sites` and the other is called `trusted sites`, below is the portion of the `squid.conf` that I am referring to:

```
acl good_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid3/good_sites"
http_access allow good_sites

acl trusted_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid3/trusted_sites"
http_reply_access allow trusted_sites
```

Any ideas?